# is there a way to get the value of select tag without submit button or its only possible in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

What i want to do is when a user select something in the select tag, the selected value will be save without clicking the submit button. Then i will get what the user select and use it in an if statement. If this is not possible can you show me a simple way to do it in jquery. i try to look for similar questions but they use arrays,while,for that make me confused.

this my current php code. if its not possible may you please show me how to convert this code to jquery.

```
<form method="post" action="speakers.php">
<label id="sortlabel">Sort By</label>
<select id="sortdrpdwn" name="sortBy">
  <option value="none" >None</option>
  <option value="name" >Name</option>
  <option value="price">Price</option>
  <option value="specialization">Specialization</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php 

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "srdatabase";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if($_POST['sortBy'] === 'none')
    {
        $select_speakers =  mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM speakers");
    }

    if($_POST['sortBy'] == 'name')
    {
        $select_speakers = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM speakers ORDER BY speaker_fullname ASC");
    }
    if($_POST['sortBy'] === 'price')
    {
        $select_speakers =  mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM speakers ORDER BY speaker_paymentcost ASC");
    }
    if($_POST['sortBy'] === 'specialization')
    {
        $select_speakers =  mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM speakers ORDER BY speaker_specialization ASC");
        echo "wqewqe";
    }

?>
```

i try to do something like this based on sir jay blanchard provide link. I try to post the var selectValue and send it to speakers.php. then echo the selectValue but its not working. Please may you tell me what is wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#sortdrpdwn").change(function(){
        var selectValue = $(this).val();
        alert("The text has been changed.");
        $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'speakers.php',
                data: {selectValue : selectValue}
            })
    });
});

</script>


</head>
<body>
<?php 
$selectValue = $_POST['selectValue'];
echo $selectValue;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery you would do this:

```
$('#sortdrpdwn').change(function(){
    var selectValue = $(this).val();
    // for testing
    console.log(selectValue);
})
```

Each time the drop down changes `selectValue` is set to the current value of the option selected.

To use this value with PHP you would then initiate an AJAX request (to a separate PHP script containing your conditions) where PHP would run the query you wish to run, then return the results.

To get started with jQuery/AJAX ***[read this](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)***.

Comment: thanks sir jay blanchard but may you show how to initiate an ajax request because i've never use AJAX.

Comment: @Red doing all of that is way too broad. You need to try it yourself and come back when you have issues. I have included a link in my answer to get you started.

Comment: i already read it but i still dont really know how to implement it. please help.. i really need to understand it.

Comment: I cannot just write the code for you @Red, you have to try it yourself.

Comment: Please do not dump code in comments and use the jQuery AJAX functions I gave you a link to. Questions about your AJAX function would be a *new* question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152809/discussion-between-red-and-jay-blanchard).